# How to return nested documents and some of its fileds via a query over main document?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have the following index on elasticsearch:

```
PUT /blog
{
"mappings": {
    "threadQ":{
        "properties": { 
            "title" : {
                   "type" : "string",
                   "analyzer" : "standard"
            },
            "body" : {
                   "type" : "string",
                   "analyzer" : "standard"
            },
            "posts":{
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "comment": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    },
                    "prototype": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    },
                    "customScore":{
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
And I added one document:

```
PUT /blog/threadQ/1
{
"title": "What is c#?",
"body": "C# is a good programming language, makes it easy to develop!",
"posts": [{
    "comment": "YEP!",
    "prototype": "Hossein Bakhtiari",
    "customScore": 2
},
{
    "comment": "NEVER EVER :O",
    "prototype": "Garpizio En Larri",
    "customScore": 3
}]
```

}
So the following query works:

```
POST /blog/threadQ/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "nested": {
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "fields": ["posts.comment"],
                        "query": "YEP"
                    }
                },
                "path": "posts"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}

And the result is the document.
Now want to make a query like this:

```
SELECT threadQ.posts.customScore FROM threadQ WHERE threadQ.posts.comment = "YEP!"
```

Please tell me how I can implement it.

Comment: is the only change that you need, that you want to bring back a specific field instead of the whole document?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem has been solved by *[dynamic templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html)*. So the new index structure is like this:

```
PUT /my_index
{
"mappings": {
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "Id":{
                "type": "integer",
                "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "name":{
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "english"
            }
        }, 
        "dynamic_templates": [
            { "en": {
                  "match":              "*", 
                  "match_mapping_type": "string",
                  "mapping": {
                      "type":           "string",
                      "analyzer":       "english"
                  }
            }}
        ]
}}}
```

And the query:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
{
 "query": {
"function_score": {
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "functions": [
    {
      "script_score": {
        "script": "doc.apple.value * _score"
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

And the result looks like this:

```
{
"took": 3,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
   "total": 5,
   "successful": 5,
   "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
   "total": 3,
   "max_score": 14,
   "hits": [
      {
         "_index": "my_index",
         "_type": "my_type",
         "_id": "2",
         "_score": 14,
         "_source": {
            "Id": 2,
            "name": "Second One",
            "iphone": 20,
            "apple": 14
         }
      },
      {
         "_index": "my_index",
         "_type": "my_type",
         "_id": "3",
         "_score": 14,
         "_source": {
            "Id": 3,
            "name": "Third One",
            "apple": 14
         }
      },
      {
         "_index": "my_index",
         "_type": "my_type",
         "_id": "1",
         "_score": 1,
         "_source": {
            "Id": 1,
            "name": "First One",
            "iphone": 2,
            "apple": 1
           }
       }
    ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To return a specific field in the document either use the [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html#search-request-fields) or [_source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) parameters

Here `_source` is used

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/blog/threadQ/_search -d '
{
"_source" : "posts.customScore",
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "nested": {
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "fields": ["posts.comment"],
                        "query": "YEP"
                    }
                },
                "path": "posts"
            }
        }]
    }
  }
}'
```

it will return:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 2.252763,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myindex",
      "_type" : "threadQ",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 2.252763,
      "_source":{"posts":[{"customScore":2},{"customScore":3}]}
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Olly, but I need to retrieve only {"customScore":2} because I want to apply some *function_score* script according to this value to sort upper level result set.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible with a nested document, you'd instead need to re-organise your data to use parent / child documents - so each `post` is a separate document in a child of `blog`